# Dialogue system using an FSM

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

In short - I've started with C# not so long ago (which means you find a lot of poor written code here) and now I'm aiming to create a dialogue system. Though my code is working as it supposed to, questions are:

- How to make everything not this lame and improve the code
- Suggestions about improving performance
- Overall advice (maybe there is some more suitable tools for doing this)

Right now I use **Finite-State Machine (FSM)** as a general concept, so that every state is a dialogue scene. The last one is made of NPC quote and set of Player responds. By now everything is pretty basic.

Here I have my class for `Player` responds:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Testing
{
    public class Player_Qoute : Label
    {
        public string Next_State { get; set; }//is used to tell, where to go next after choosing particular respond
    }
```

It's inherited from `Label` and has one additional field - next stage number, which is added in this function:

```
private void NPC_Quote(string path, string specification, RichTextBox info)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);//creating StremReader to read NPC quotes from .txt
    string line = "";//Creating string variable to read from
    try
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)//reading file line-by-line until the end
        {
            if (line.Contains(specification))//if line contains specified "tag"
            {
                line = line.Remove(0, specification.Length);//removing "tag" from line
                info.Text += line + "\n";//adding NPC line to the output field 
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Problem reading file");
    }
}
```

This function parse through .txt file, searching for lines tagged `NPC_stage_n`, where `n` - is a number of stage. This number is present at the end of every Player respond in .txt file and I put it in the `Next_Stage` field of `Player_Quote` objects. The same idea is applied here, but now I dynamically create Player's responds (number of which varies from stage to stage). Now tag for search looks like `Player_stage_n`. I'm facing some issues with appropriate placing of quotes on the GroupBox - sometimes they are missing a line or words, but I'm working on it (but, actually, can use some help):

```
void Quotes_Generation(string path, string specification, GroupBox parent)
{
    parent.Controls.Clear();//deleting previous Player qoutes
    int step = 0;//auxilary variable to separate quotes from each other by heigth
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);//StreamReader to read Player responds from .txt
    string line = "";
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(specification))
        {
            Player_Qoute quote = new Player_Qoute();//inherited from Label;
            quote.Name = "qoute_" + line.Remove(specification.Length, line.Length - specification.Length);
            quote.Location = new Point(10, 20 + step);
            quote.Size = new Size(360, 10);
            quote.Text = line.Remove(0, specification.Length);//deleting "search tag" from text
            quote.Text = quote.Text.Remove(quote.Text.Length-3, 3); //here we are deleting 3-digit number at the end of the string 
            //this number will show what is the next state of the dialogue if this Player respond is chosen.
            quote.Next_State = line.Remove(0,line.Length - 3);//storing 3-digit number in Player_Quote property
            using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())//part of code which was borrowed from StackOverFlow and wasn't properly understood by me
            {
                SizeF size = g.MeasureString(quote.Text, quote.Font, 264);
                quote.Height = (int)Math.Ceiling(size.Height);
                quote.Text = quote.Text;
            }
            quote.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.Quote_Click);//creating event for choosing this respond
            parent.Controls.Add(quote);//adding respond to GroupBox
            step += (quote.Height+3);//increasing step
            if (parent.Height < step)//enlarging GroupBox
            {
                parent.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(parent.Width, step + 50);
                parent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(parent.Width, step + 50);
            }
        }
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

And here is the `Quote_Click` event:

```
private void Quote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Player_Qoute current = sender as Player_Qoute;//recognizing the sender
        richTextBox1.Text +=  Player_Name + "   -  " + current.Text + "\n";//adding Player respond with Player name to RichTextBox
        NPC_Quote(Application.StartupPath + "/Readme.txt", "NPC_stage_" + current.Next_State + ":", richTextBox1);//Adding new NPC line according to chosen respond
        Quotes_Generation(Application.StartupPath + "/Readme.txt", "Player_stage_" + current.Next_State + ":", groupBox1);//refreshing responds according to previous actions
    }
```

Here's an example from a file that includes the dialog:

> ```
> NPC_stage_001:Morte - Hey, Chief! What's up?
> Player_stage_001:[ignore the levitating skull]002
> Player_stage_001:Where am I?.003
> Player_stage_001:Oh, a talking skull!004
> Player_stage_001:Who are you?005
>
> NPC_stage_002:Morte  -  Hey, Chief - are you okay? You don't look like this local zombies... Well, maybe you smell like them, but still.
> Player_stage_002:Could you remind me - who are you?005
> Player_stage_002:Kidding jokes with me, aren't you?008
> Player_stage_002:Sorry, just trying to catch my mind. What is this place?003
> Player_stage_002:[continue ignoring and explore the room]010
>
> NPC_stage_003:Morte - O-o-o, you don't recognize good old Mortuary? I believe it isn't your first visit here. Well, this place
> is a Sigil's crematory.
> Player_stage_003:Good start!007
> Player_stage_003:And why am I here?006
>
> NPC_stage_004:Morte - Ha-ha-ha, this joke is a centuries old!
> Player_stage_004:But still hit's the target!010
> Player_stage_004:I'm sorry, mate...009
>
> NPC_stage_005:Morte - Me? I'm the head of Vekna! Well, not exactly - my name is Morte.
> Player_stage_005:your_quote.next_stage...
>
> And etc.
> ```

Comment: Could you please post the content of the text files that you are using?

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwqcJObdLMAwYnotTmU2SENfVEU/view?usp=sharing . sorry, it took a while to translate a sample to English.

Answer (score 7):

I want to talk about just one aspect of what makes this particular method so difficult to read, understand and maintain:

```
private void NPC_Quote(string path, string specification, RichTextBox info)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path);//creating StremReader to read NPC quotes from .txt
    string line = "";//Creating string variable to read from
    try
    {
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)//reading file line-by-line until the end
        {
            if (line.Contains(specification))//if line contains specified "tag"
            {
                line = line.Remove(0, specification.Length);//removing "tag" from line
                info.Text += line + "\n";//adding NPC line to the output field 
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Problem reading file");
    }
}
```

Let's try to describe what this method does in English.  It opens a file, reads every line of the file looking for a line with a particular tag, removes the tag, updates a text box, and handles errors.

Did you notice something about that description?  It said nothing whatsoever about the business domain of the method!  The "business domain" is a description of what the method does in context of what the program is *for*: interacting with an NPC in a game.

What you've done here is *thoroughly* mixed up back-end mechanism logic -- opening files, searching for a tag -- with *display* logic -- updating a text box -- with error management logic, and with *business logic*.  Methods that try to do so much mean that it becomes impossible to change the rules of the game - the actual business of the program - without changing code that touches all the mechanisms that underly it.

Refactor all of this stuff. You have a concept: NPC. Make a type that represents the NPC.

```
class NPC
{
  private static string quotesFile = @"npcquotes.txt";
  static public string Quote(string tag)
  {
    var line = File.ReadLines(quotesFile)
      .Where(line => line.StartsWith(tag))
      .Select(line => line.Remove(0, tag.Length))
      .FirstOrDefault();
    return line ?? "";
  }
}
```

Good heavens look at how much nicer that is. (Not to mention the correctness errors that I've fixed. If your tag was at the *end* of a string it would still be matched in your implementation.)

Now you can say `NPC.Quote(tag)` and get back a string. Now write a class that represents **the user interface of the game**. That is the thing that should be updating the text box, not the code that reads the NPC strings.

Moreover: if later on you decide that you want to have the strings in memory instead of in a file, now you have only ONE place to change the code:

```
class NPC
{
  private static string quotesFile = @"npcquotes.txt";
  private Dictionary<string, string> quotes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
  {
     { "blah", "blah blah blah blah" },
     { "foo", "foo bar foo bar" }
  };
  static public string Quote(string tag)
  {
    return quotes.ContainsKey(tag) ? quotes[tag] : "";
  }
}
```

By encapsulating the logic in a method that does only one thing you become free to change the implementation of that method without impacting the UI, the game logic, and so on.

What about the error handling? Well, you need to think this through better anyways. What experience do you really want the user of the game to have when an error occurs? Is a dialog that says "file operation failed, you are borked" really that useful?  Work out carefully what the error handling semantics are for your program and then implement them.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now, when you've stressed out problems and suggested great ideas I'll try to make everything at least not that bad. Thank you once again.